# restarting nginx that installed a user defines directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I try to use the commands for the nginx but I installed it in /home/user/nginx folder instead of default system folder on root. However I cannot command nginx from there. How could I do that? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `HUP` signal to process by `` kill -HUP `pidof nginx` ``. This should reloaad configuration, and restart passenger.

Comment: Do I need to start only nginx or passenger and nginx together

Comment: You start nginx process and it starts a passenger on demand. When you want reset it just send a `HUP` to nginx process.